# Positioning of font awesome icons in carousel indicators

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use font-awesome icons as my carousel indicators for bootstrap 4.

HTML: -

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" data-interval="false" class="active"><i class="carousel-fa fa fa-user"></i></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" data-interval="false" ><i class="carousel-fa fa fa-institution"></i></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" data-interval="false" ><i class="carousel-fa fa fa-graduation-cap"></i></li>
  </ol>
  <div id="about-me" class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:-

```
.carousel-indicators li {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }

  .carousel-fa {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: -36px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: grey;
  }
```

The background colour and border comes at the exactly same position where I  want but the fa icons are not coming. When I put `left:1000px` in `.carousel-fa` class then they come but I get a horizontal scroll bar below and the borders shift to the right.

Without `left:1000px;`
[image: Without <code>left:1000px;</code>]

With `left:1000px;` (You can see the horizontal scroll & borders shifted to the right, though now the fa icons are in exact place where I want.)
[image: With <code>left:1000px;</code> (You can see the horizontal scroll & borders shifted to the right, though now the fa icons are in exact place where I want.)]

Please help!!

Edit:- Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0ngr0bhq/

Comment: have you tried by changing the value of `    position: relative;` . try to put the value as absolute of fixed.

Comment: `position: absolute;` is working same as above and for fixed I don't get my icons whatever maybe the value of `left`.

Comment: could you please provide the code in fiddle?

Comment: Added! Sorry for not adding it previously.

Comment: Its ok ... Try the   `display: inline;` in the class `.carousel-fa`. This will resolve your issue.

Comment: Does the suggestion help you?? please let me know.

Comment: Oh yes! It worked. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161453/discussion-between-code-lver-and-hemakshi-sachdev).

Comment: Can you come on chat bia above link...